# Troubles after updating ipython (%matplotlib nbagg)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed anaconda distro, I usualy run `ipython notebook --pylab inline`. I updated `ipython` using `pip install` (windows 8.1) and I don't have to write --pylab inline to start anymore

I started writing in the cell: `%matplotlib nbagg` or `matplotlib.use['nbagg']`, but when I plot something it shows this empty box:
[image]

I was expecting the interactive plotting box.

The ipython log shows:

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm: 7cfe982045bb4d0db0f14deff7258130
```

Comment: I think this issue is caused by not having the latest version of matplotlib. Can you please check the `console` where you started `ipython notebook` for error messages and add them to your question? This will make it easier for others with a similar problem to find your question.

Comment: Also note that using  `ipython notebook --pylab inline` is now deprecated. Instead you can write `%matplotlib inline` for static inline images, or `%matplotlib notebook`/``%matplotlib nbagg`  for interactive plots (as you did in your question) in the first line of the notebook.

Comment: I get the same console error but in my case I do see the plots

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess this issue is caused by a too old version of `matplotlib`. Using `%matplotlib nbagg` with `ipython>=3.0` requires `matplotlib>=1.4.3` (Note that `%matplotlib notebook` and `%matplotlib nbagg` are now synonyms).

Updating matplotlib via `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` will probably fix this issue. See also my [`issue-7797`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7797) on github. Thanks to **jenshnielsen** for this information.

Answer (score 2):

Should update both matplotlib and ipython...

```
sudo pip install -U ipython
sudo pip install -U matplotlib
```

on windows:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
pip install --upgrade ipython
```

Comment: The deceiving thing in my case was that the error mentioned a "TCLError"